# Get right clicked item from context menu inside wrappanel inside itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, eventargs

I have an ItemsControl which has a WrapPanel inside of it. Inside that WrapPanel I have a context menu. The whole thing looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxList}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
              <WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                  <MenuItem Header="Remove from list">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="RemoveCheckBox">
                          <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs"/>
                        </cal:ActionMessage>
                      </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
              </WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
            </WrapPanel>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
```

But I cant get the actual right clicked element like this. Source of the event args is just the clicked menu item of the context menu. How can I get the actual clicked element?